# Keeping beef jerky dry?

Tags: beef, dehydrating, jerky

I made some beef jerky, and I am wanting to mail some to family and friends.  I don't have any of those silica gel packets to absorb moisture - is there anything else I can put in the baggie that will absorb any moisture as effectively as those silica gel packets?

Comment: Air popped popcorn, else try uncooked rice. Salted popped popcorn may be available at grocery stores.

Comment: Maybe put the uncooked rice/popcorn in cheese cloth, tied up, to keep it together.

Comment: BTW, easiest way to make popcorn -- Alton Brown's paper bag in microwave. http://www.goodeatsfanpage.com/Season2/Corn/CornTranscript.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several options:

- wrap jerky in paper napkins/towels before putting in the baggie
- put jerky in a paper bag and then in a plastic one
- put some uncooked rice, as Optionparty has mentioned

The method you choose also depends on how long it takes the mail to be delivered. Rice is the most long-lasting way, but it will also add the most weight to the package. Paper bags and towels are equally effective, but they won't do for longer than a few days.

Whichever you do, make sure the baggie is well closed to prevent any moisture from outside getting in.